# Create a temporary table in python to join with a sql table

Tags: python, sql, join, vertica

I have the following data in a vertica db, `Mytable`:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| A  |     5 |
| B  |     9 |
| C  |    10 |
| D  |     7 |
+----+-------+
```

I am trying to create a query in python to access a vertica data base. In python I have a list:

```
ID_list= ['A', 'C']
```

I would like to create a query that basically inner joins `Mytable` with the `ID_list` and then I could make a `WHERE` query.
So it will be basically something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
INNER JOIN ID_list
    ON Mytable.ID = ID_list as temp_table
WHERE Value = 5
```

I don't have writing rights on the data base, so the table needs to be created localy. Or is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think you can create a temp table locally, but why not just use the values directly in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Well the ID_list is fairly long, would that work? I mean worst case I can create a loop.

Comment: I don't know Python, so sadly I can't give the full answer, but you can use `WHERE IN (5, 10, ...)` if Vertica supports that.  Use a parameterized query to avoid injection.

Comment: So basically something like this:
`SELECT*
(SELECT *
FROM Mytable WHERE ID IN (ID_list))
WHERE Value = 5`

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a small table, then you can do as Tim suggested and create an in-list.

I kind of prefer to do this using python ways, though. I would probably also make ID_list a `set` as well to keep from having dups, etc.

```
in_list = '(%s)' % ','.join(str(id) for id in ID_list)
```

or better use bind variables (depends on the client you are using, and probably not strictly necessary if you are dealing with a set of ints since I can't imagine a way to inject sql with that):

```
in_list = '(%s)' % ','.join(['%d'] * len(ID_list)
```

and send in your ID_list as a parameter list for your `cursor.execute`. This method is positional, so you'll need to arrange your bind parameters correctly.

If you have a very, very large list... you could create a local temp and load it before doing your query with join.

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE mytable ( id INTEGER );

COPY mytable FROM STDIN;
-- Or however you need to load the data. Using python, you'll probably need to stream in a list using `cursor.copy`
```

Then join to mytable.

I wouldn't bother doing the latter with a very small number of rows, too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the approach from Tim:

```
# create a String of all the ID_list so they can be inserted into a SQL query
Sql_string='(';
for ss in ID_list:
    Sql_string= Sql_string + " " + str(ss) + ","
Sql_string=Sql_string[:-1] + ")"

"SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE ID IN " + Sql_string) as temp 
Where Value = 5"
```

works surprisingly fast